# Android Studio - JavaDoc comments not generating

Tags: android, android-studio, comments, javadoc

I have one problem with the comments in Android Studio.
My template file (File Header) Is like this:

```
/**
 * Created by ${USER} on ${DATE}.
 */
```

When I create new class, or Interface my comment header gets automatically generated, and this works.

But when I generate: activity, fragment, application, services, the comment does not generate. I really do not know where is the problem.

Here is the Activity template description. But when I create new Activity, the comment does not appear, and every time I need to retype it.

```
package ${PACKAGE_NAME};

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

#parse("File Header.java")
public class ${NAME} extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To generate comments type `/**` above the method name and press enter. You can also use a tool under Android Studio menu:

> Tools > Generate JavaDoc

Comment: this is not what I was looking for I want that the comments  are automatically generated when I create the activity or fragment.... 
not type "/**"... I want that this is generated automatically like when I create new class. When I create new class, the comment is already there.